# How to parse JSON larger than memory?

Tags: c++, json, memory, nlohmann-json

I'm working on a project that involves a large JSON file, basically a multidimensional array dumped in JSON form, but the overall size would be larger than the amount of memory I have. If I load it in as a string and then parse the string, that will consume all of the memory.

Are there any methods to limit the memory consumption, such as only retrieving data between specific indices? Could I implement that using solely the Nlohmann json library/the standard libraries?

Comment: Hint: Streaming parser or [NDJSON](http://ndjson.org).

Comment: multidimensional array of what? If the answer is numbers, JSON's probably not the right choice for the same reason we don't use JSON as an image format.

Comment: @user4581301 Array of structs -- each one has a std::tuple of ints, ints themselves, and an std::vector<float>

Answer (score 2):

RapidJSON and others can do it.  Here's an example program using RapidJSON's "SAX" (streaming) API: https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson/blob/master/example/simplereader/simplereader.cpp

This way, you'll get an event (callback) for each element encountered during parsing.  The memory consumption of the parsing itself will be quite small.

Answer (score 1):

Using DAW JSON Link, https://github.com/beached/daw_json_link , you can create an iterator pair/range and iterate over the JSON array 1 record at a time.  The library also has routines for working with JSONL, which is common in large datasets.

For opening the file, I would use something like mmap/virtual alloc to handle that for us.  The examples in the library use this via the `daw::filesystem::memory_mapped_file_t` type that abstracts the file mapping.

With that, the memory mapped file allows the OS to page the data in/out as needed, and the iterator like interface keeps the memory requirement to that of one array element at a time.

The following demonstrates this, using a simple Record that

```cpp
struct Point {
  int x;
  int y;
};
```

The program to do this looks like

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <daw/daw_memory_mapped_file.h>
#include <daw/json/daw_json_iterator.h>
#include <daw/json/daw_json_link.h>
#include <iostream>

struct Point {
  double x;
  double y;
};

namespace daw::json {
    template<>
    struct json_data_contract<Point> {
        using type =
          json_member_list<json_number<"x">, json_number<"y">>;
    };
}

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
  assert( argc >= 1 );
  auto json_doc = daw::filesystem::memory_mapped_file_t<char>( argv[1] );
  assert( json_doc.size( ) > 2 );
  auto json_range = daw::json::json_array_range<Point>( json_doc );
  auto sum_x = 0.0;
  auto sum_y = 0.0;
  auto count = 0ULL;
  for( Point p: json_range ) {
    sum_x += p.x;
    sum_y += p.y;
    ++count;
  }
  sum_x /= static_cast<double>( count );
  sum_y /= static_cast<double>( count );
  std::cout << "Centre Point (" << sum_x << ", " << sum_y << ")\n";
}
```

https://jsonlink.godbolt.org/z/xoxEd1z6G

Answer (score 0):

Could you please specify the context of your question

- What programming language you are using (NodeJS, Vanilla JavaScript, Java, React)
- What environment your code is running (Monolithic app on a server, AWS Lambda, Serverless)

Computing large JSON files can consume a lot of memory resources on a server, perhaps, make your app to crash.
I have experienced first-hand, that manipulating large JSON files on my local computer with 8 GB of memory RAM is not a problem using a NodeJS script to compute the large JSON files payloads. However, trying to run those large JSON payloads in an application running on a server give me problems too.

I hope this helps.

Comment: He has already specified the programming language (C++) by using the [tag:c++] tag in the question.